# Not able to print list elements in for loop

Tags: python, list, generator

I have the following list:

`result_lines = ['hello', 'bye']`

I trying to form a one-liner to print the elements of the list as follows:

`print(line for line in result_lines)`

Expected Result:

hello

bye

Output (that I am getting):

<generator object execute_commands.. at 0x7f9e37a9b900>

EDIT:

Also, how is the above approach different from :

```
for line in result_lines:
    print(line)
```

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Surround the everything inside print in brackets, so for example `print([line for line in result_lines])`  should work. For more check out [list compehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehensions#list-comprehensions)

Comment: `line for line in result_lines` is a generator expression, so it prints a representation of the generator object created by the expression. Since you want to print each element of the generator, expand it into a sequence using brackets. Note that you can get the same result by simply `print(result_lines)`

Comment: Your question title says "Not able to print list elements in for loop"; but you showed us code that is **not a for loop** and complained that it doesn't give you the desired output, then you showed code that **is** a for loop and that **does, in fact, work**.

Answer (score 2):

As you see, you have a generator.  You need to create a list from the generator.

```
print([line for line in result_lines])
```

or

```
print(list(line for line in result_lines))
```

Also, you don't really need a generator/loop here, you can just do

```
print(result_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this,

```
result_lines = ['hello', 'bye']
print(*result_lines, sep = "\n")
```

use * to pass all elements without binding them in a list and use `sep="\n"` to every element onto the next line.

Answer (score 1):

In `Python` if you want to work with `list comprehension` you have to add square braces, like this...

```
list_ = [element for element in iterable]
```

...that's equivalent to...

```
list_ = list(element for element in iterable)
```

...and to...

```
list_ = [] # equivalent to list()
for element in iterable:
    list_.append(element)
```

---

In you case you have to add square brackets, like this:

```
print([line for line in result_lines])
```

But you can also solve your problem using the `built-in` function `print`, like this:

```
print(*result_lines, sep='\n')
```

since in Python you can use `*` operator to convert an iterable to a printable iterable.